# Ansible: XML module to read an attribute value

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible to get the element value in my case value "7.01.12 (125)". I am getting error: does not reference a node!
here is my XML:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ZSI="http://www.zolera.com/schemas/ZSI/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:ns1="urn:zola2">
      <ns1:getVersionResponse>
         <Result>7.01.12 (125)</Result>
      </ns1:getVersionResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Here is the xml playbook part:

```
- name: XML
      xml:
        xmlstring: "{{ version.content }}"
        namespaces: 
          ns1: urn:zola2
          SOAP-ENV: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
        xpath: //SOAP-ENV:Body/ns1:getVersionResponse/Result/text()
        content: text
      register: answer  
    - debug:
       var: answer.matches
```

By removing the text() from the xpath I don't get the error and the answer.matches = "Result": "7.01.12 (125)"
I just need the value "7.01.12 (125)". I tried my xpath on the XPath Tester / Evaluator and I got the correct result.
What I am missing here? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it looks like that's just the way the `xml` module thinks about `xpath:` -- that it will always result in a `Node` or `Element`, and that's what is going to appear in the `matches` list of that `register`

However, you can extract the value from the matched element without having to specify the element name twice via [`dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#items2dict-filter):

```
- xml:
    # as you have it
  register: answer
- set_fact:
    the_text: >-
      {{ answer.matches[0]
      | dict2items
      | map(attribute="value")
      | first }}
```